# How to get products by specific attributes in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, product, magento2

### I have this query:

Here i'm looking for the product passing the $product_id variable.

```
$product_id = 2047;
$attr_color = 54;
$attr_size = 170;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

I want to get the specific product variation that match with the attr_color and attr_size variables. ¿How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get the specific product variation with the **attr_color** and
>   **attr_size** you need to get first that attribute and then pass your **attribute_id** to that attribute.

Try below code:

```
            $product_id = 2047;
            $attr_color = 54;

          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
          $_product = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');    

         if ($_product->usesSource()) {
           $_product = $_product->getSource()->getOptionText($attr_color);
        }
           return $_product;
```

Similarly you can do it for **attribute_size** as well.

Comment: @AndresGonzales Happy To help keep helping :)